# Dtd or Xsd Sql definition

Tags: sql, xsd, dtd, ansi-sql

Where can I find a xsd or dtd specification for SQL? I have tried bnf ready files to transform without success.

Comment: I doubt you find those as DTD and XSD is meant the describe XML and or related XML ones like HTML or SOAP not to describe SQL syntax. Also this question is offtopic for stackoverflow as you should not be asking for off site resources

Comment: I think manual converting BNF to XSD is needed as it might be possible to use here..i would advice using XSD over DTD as it has more features